# Loading Blob from BlobStorage into XslCompiledTransform.Load()

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a XSLT File in AzureBlobStorage.

I need to Load that Blob into XslCompiledTransform.Load().

```
CloudBlockBlob blob_xslt = blobClient.GetContainerReference("containerName").GetBlockBlobReference("file_xslt.xslt");
CloudBlockBlob blob_xml = blobClient.GetContainerReference("ContainerName").GetBlockBlobReference("file_xml.xml");
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
xslt.Load(blob_xslt.Uri.ToString()); // Cant Able to load that blob here .. 
xslt.Transform(blob_xml.StorageUri.ToString(), XmlWriter.Create(stringBuilder));
```

I had tried using MemoryStream and StreamReader etc..

Please help in this..

Comment: The blob should be publicly accessible. What happens when you take the blob URL and paste it in browser's address bar? Are you able to see the contents of the file or are you getting a 404 error?

Comment: resource not found error is coming. But in that container blob is found. is there any other method to load that file ? @GauravMantri

Comment: What do you mean by `But in that container blob is found`? Do you mean you're able to see the blob when exploring it in a storage explorer?

Comment: when i make the blob public , The xml file is loaded as html when i try to load the blob url. if not ie.. Private (resourse not found) error is thrown.  @GauravMantri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer will work for your question

```
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = GetCloudBlobContainer();
        CloudBlob blob_xslt = blobClient.GetContainerReference("container1").GetBlobReference("name.xslt");

        CloudBlob blob_xml = blobClient.GetContainerReference("container2").GetBlobReference(name.xml);

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
        settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
        settings.CloseOutput = false;
        string xml_string = null;
        string xslt_string = null;
        using (var xmlstream = await blob_xml.OpenReadAsync())
        {
            using (var xsltstream = await blob_xslt.OpenReadAsync())
            {

                StreamReader xmlreader = new StreamReader(xmlstream);
                StreamReader xsltreader = new StreamReader(xsltstream);
                while (!xmlreader.EndOfStream && !xsltreader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    xml_string = xmlreader.ReadToEnd();
                    xslt_string = xsltreader.ReadToEnd();
                }
                byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xslt_string);
                var tmpFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
                var tmpFileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(tmpFile);
                tmpFileStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                tmpFileStream.Close();
                xslt.Load(tmpFile);

                byte[] byteArray1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml_string);
                var tmpFile1 = Path.GetTempFileName();
                var tmpFileStream1 = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(tmpFile1);
                tmpFileStream1.Write(byteArray1, 0, byteArray1.Length);
                tmpFileStream1.Close();

                xslt.Transform(tmpFile1, XmlWriter.Create(stringBuilder, settings));

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried `MemoryStream` and it works. See code below.

```
var stream_xslt = new MemoryStream();
await blob_xslt.DownloadToStreamAsync(stream_xslt);
stream_xslt.Position = 0;

var stream_xml = new MemoryStream();
await blob_xml.DownloadToStreamAsync(stream_xml);
stream_xml.Position = 0;

XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
xslt.Load(XmlReader.Create(stream_xslt));
xslt.Transform(XmlReader.Create(stream_xml), 
XmlWriter.Create(stringBuilder));
```

To access blob using uri, you have to use [sas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1#example-create-a-service-sas-on-a-blob) uri if its access level is not public. Since you can connect to storage account, downloading blob to stream may be the preference if it does work.